# How to use keyword 'any' in Swift Generic Protocol?

Tags: swift, generics

I have an error: "Member 'getAnswer' cannot be used on value of type 'any DataServiceProtocol'; consider using a generic constraint instead". I know that compiler can not define a type, but I can not find a solution.

```
class Main: ObservableObject {

    @Published var answer: [Any] = []
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    let answerGetter: any DataServiceProtocol

    init(dataService: any DataServiceProtocol) {
        self.answerGetter = dataService
        loadAnswer()
    }

    func loadAnswer() {
        answerGetter.getAnswer(message: "")
            .sink { _ in
            
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] returnedAnswer in
                self?.answer = returnedAnswer
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}

protocol DataServiceProtocol {
    associatedtype T
    func getAnswer(message: String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], Error>
}

class FirstGetter: DataServiceProtocol {
    
    typealias T = FirstResponse
    let stringUrl = "https://myfirstapi"

    func getAnswer(message: String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], Error> {}
}

class SecondGetter: DataServiceProtocol {
    
    typealias T = SecondResponse
    let stringUrl = "https://mysecondapi"
    
    func getAnswer(message: String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], Error> {}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use 'any' here?